# I am trying to reverse a two dimensional array and keep getting a null exception

Tags: java, function, methods, reverse

Here is my method that is suppose to reverse the array.
(Also, keep in mind that this method can receive a jagged array)

```
    public static int[][] reverse(int[][]a){

int[][] rev = new int[a.length][];

int row = a.length;

for(int x=0;x<a.length;x++){
   int col = a[x].length-1;
   for(int y=0; y< a[x].length;y++){

       rev[row-1][col-1]= a[x][y];
       col--;

       }
   row--;
   }

   return rev;


}// reverse method
```

I keep getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Home.reverse(Home.java:259)
at Home.main(Home.java:56)
```

Java Result: 1

Here is my main that calls that method

```
int[][] two = {{1,2,3,4},{0,1,2},{9},{1,3,5,7}};
System.out.println("The size of array os " + ar.length);
System.out.println("The columns of array is " + ar[0].length); 

int[][] rev;
//int[] b = concatenate(ar);
//int[] c = concatenate(two);
//int[][] rev = reverse(ar);

//for(int x=0;x<c.length;x++){System.out.println("worked" + c[x]);}

rev = reverse(two);

//for(int x = 0;x<rev.length;x++){
//  for(int y = 0;y<rev[x].length;y++){
//    System.out.print(rev[x][y]);
//}
//}
for(int x=0;x<rev.length;x++){
for(int y=0;y<rev[x].length;y++){
    System.out.print(rev[x][y]);
}
}

}// main
```

So my question is really, where did I go wrong?
I traced my reverse method and it looks like it should be doing its job but apparently not.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since it doesn't apply here.

Comment: what exactly to you mean by reverse? Your code looks like its switching the top left corner with the bottom right corner, but what is it supposed to do with a jagged array?

Comment: take int[][]two = {{1,2,3,4},{0,1,2},{9},{1,3,5,7}}

Comment: reverse so it can be int[][] rev = {{7,5,3,1},{9},{2,1,0},{4,3,2,1}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say this line

```
int[][] rev = new int[a.length][];
```

You have created an array of length `a.length` of arrays, but the internal arrays are all `null`.  So you are getting a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
rev[row-1][col-1]= a[x][y];
```

You need to create your internal arrays inside the first for loop.  This will satisfy your "jagged array" requirement.

```
for(int x=0;x<a.length;x++){
   int col = a[x].length-1;
   rev[row-1] = new int[a[x].length];  // Add this to create differing lengths.
   for(int y=0; y< a[x].length;y++){
```

Answer (score 3):

Your array `rev` has not been initialized in its second coordinate. After your declaration `int[][] rev = new int[a.length][]`, all your `rev[i]` are `null` objects (arrays are objects, even for primitive types). To avoid that, initialize with `int[][] rev = new int[a.length][a[0].length]` or with `rev[i] = new int[a[i].length]` or so, if the array is jagged.

Comment: But then it would a create a two dimensional array with a fixed amount of columns per row, no?

Comment: @MaCo you're right. The right way to do it in the general case is `rev[i] = new int[a[x].length];`. Will add this to the answer. Thanks.