# Jagged array; check for column-wise value increase

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This method is simple, there is 2D array, not a rectangle, the purpose is to check the values in each column whether they are increasing or not, if they are in an  increasing order, return true, else return false.

The shape of the array is like the following, it is a [Young Tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau)
{
[1,4,5,10,11],
[2,6,8],
[3,9,12],
[7]
}

**The main properties of a young tableaux:**

- it consists of cells which are filled with integers, and arranged in
  left-justified rows,
- no row is longer than a preceding row,
- from left to right in any row, and down any column the integers are increasing,
- the set of integers used is {1, 2, . . . , n} where n is the number
  of cells

**How I solve it?**
My approach is simple, first convert this 2D array into a rectangle matrix, if some position is empty, then filled it with 0.

Then check the column one by one, if found a error, then break, and return the result.

It works, I just wonder if there is a better apporach for this.

```
public static boolean columnValuesIncrease(int[][] t) {
    //How many columns are there?
    int columnCounts = t[0].length;
    int rowCounts = t.length;

    //create a rectangle matrix, fill 0 when outIndex
    int[][] addZero = new int[rowCounts][columnCounts];
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCounts; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < t[0].length; col++) {
            try {
                addZero[row][col] = t[row][col];
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                addZero[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //Let's check the damn column!
    boolean mark = true;
    myLoop:
    for (int col = 0; col < columnCounts; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCounts; row++) {
            if (row + 1 < rowCounts && col + 1 < columnCounts) {
                if (addZero[row + 1][col] != 0) {
                    mark = addZero[row][col] <
                            addZero[row + 1][col] ? true : false;
                }
            }
            if (!mark) {
                break myLoop;
            }
        }
    }
    return mark;
}
```

Comment: you should look to data structures, and pointers

Comment: In your nested loop, you have `col < t[0].length`. Are you assured that the first row has the max number of columns? If so, you are depending on hitting the catch to populate a strictly nxm array. Why not just do everything in one nested loop without using extra storage?

Comment: Also, what is the expected output for this case `{{1 0 1},{2 3},{3 3 4}}`?

Comment: @DebosmitRay OK, my fault, has edited the post, it is a  Young tableaux, in fact.

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580370/i-am-trying-to-reverse-a-two-dimensional-array-and-keep-getting-a-null-exception for inverting a jagged array. Also, as a general tip, you should never use exception handling for program logic.

Comment: @Chill Thanks for the other method. And thanks for the exception tips. Remember it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach takes a row. It considers 'this' row and the one after it. It considers `N` number of columns, where `N` is the minimum of the number of columns in this row and the row after. In math, if `R` is the number of rows in this 2D matrix, take some r<sub>1</sub>: r<sub>1</sub> ∈ [0, R) and r<sub>2</sub> = r<sub>1</sub> + 1. Then, N = min{*num_cols(r<sub>1</sub>), num_cols(r<sub>2</sub>)*}.

In column `n`, where `n ∈ [0, N]`, if the value at the column in the next row happens to be *smaller* than the value in the preceding row, it returns false. If everything else worked, it returns true.

```
public static boolean columnValuesIncrease(int[][] t) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < t.length - 1 ; i++) 
        for(int j = 0 ; j < Math.min(t[i].length, t[i+1].length) ; j++) 
            if(t[i][j] > t[i+1][j])
                return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How about {{0 0 0}, {0 1 0}, {500 0}}?

Comment: @Chill It is a tableau, so your sets don't follow the rule.

Comment: @Chill Please refer to [[wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau)].

Comment: @Chill Even otherwise. Is there a reason you think that case shouldn't fail?

Comment: I think I messed that one up, but I don't think the assumption that it is a tableau makes much sense. The whole point is to validate that it fits the rules, right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the huge differences of LOC between our approach really break my heart :( REALLY THANKS!

Comment: @Chill I ran a few tests before posting that function. For non-asinine input, it seemed to work. Please let me know if I have missed something obvious. :)

Comment: @AlbertGao Not a worry, buddy. Made it a little smaller :p. Only here to help. :)

Comment: Here is a question, Math.min(t[i].length, t[i+1].length]), this line ensure that there will never be a OutOfIndex, but I just wonder, the Min of these two is predictable, it will always be t[i+1], right? t[i+1].length should always be less or equal to t[i].length. I try to omit the Math.Min, but it can't pass the test...

Comment: @AlbertGao Iff it is a Young tableau will that work; otherwise it will fail. I think it is best left there since it will not be that much of a performance issue.

Comment: Thanks, it must be there, we need to handle the last-row senario... This is why I get a OutOfIndex exception when I try to omit the Math.Min. Very briliant logic. Thanks!

Comment: That's the part where I got tripped up. This is a clever implementation.